# How to use PCF (SOFT) shadows in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, rendering, shadow

How do you apply the PCF (SOFT) shadow type as seen in the [Three.js online editor](https://threejs.org/editor/) to your renderer in the form of javascript code?

[image: Image of three.js editor panel showing "PCF (SOFT)" option]

Comment: Take a look at this topic: https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/lights/shadows/DirectionalLightShadow And there is the line: `renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;`. Also this doc is helpful: https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer.shadowMap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use that type of shadows you need to use the respective type of shadow map:

```
renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;
```

Related links:

- https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/lights/shadows/DirectionalLightShadow
- https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer.shadowMap

r115